# Delete a column from TFRecord Dataset (for feature selection)

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tfrecord, tfx

I am trying to implement a Feature Selection component with the following plan in mind:

#### The implementation

- Component takes and `InputArtifact[Example]` as input
- Since the data is stored in the form of TFRecords in the URI of the input artifact, I convert it into compatible numpy dictionaries and use sklearn to come up with the list of features selected
- I delete the required features from the input example **directly** to produce put it in `OutputArtifact[Example]` (which has the same structure but fewer columns)

I am done with the first and second point, but am not able to figure out how to delete the selected columns directly in the TFRecord Dataset itself (which I am getting using `tf.data.TFRecordDataset(train_uri, compression_type='GZIP')`)

Comment: Could you please refer this [blog](https://towardsdatascience.com/tfrecords-explained-24b8f2133282).Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It took me some time to figure out (with the help of the blog linked by TensorFlow Support in the comments), but here is a workaround!

```py
split_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset("path_to_original_dataset.gzip", compression_type='GZIP')
```

```py
with tf.io.TFRecordWriter(path = "path_to_new_TFRecord.gzip", options="GZIP") as writer:
      for split_record in split_dataset.as_numpy_iterator():
        example = tf.train.Example()
        example.ParseFromString(split_record)

        updated_example = update_example(selected_features, example)

        writer.write(updated_example.SerializeToString())
```

Here, `updated_example` is a custom function I used that takes the parsed example, processes it and returns the processed example!

```py
# update example with selected features
def update_example(selected_features, orig_example):
  result = {}
  for key, feature in orig_example.features.feature.items():
    if key in selected_features:
      result[key] = orig_example.features.feature[key]
    
    new_example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=result))
    return new_example
```

Instead of deleting the column (as I wasn't able to find a way to do so), I just created a new example feature-by-feature and returned it!

Comment: you've got indentation problems in your `update_example` fn.